# Android, OpenGL convert vertices values to pixels

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I'm creating application to Android using OpenGL ES.
I created rectangle using following vertices.

```
private float vertices[] = {
          -1.0f,  0.5f, 0.0f,  // 0, Top Left
          -1.0f, -0.5f, 0.0f,  // 1, Bottom Left
           1.0f, -0.5f, 0.0f,  // 2, Bottom Right
           1.0f,  0.5f, 0.0f,  // 3, Top Right
    };

private short[] indices = { 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3 };
```

How do find location in pixels for this rectangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your viewport, projection and model view matrices. position of a vertex on the screen is calculated with the formula like: `projectionMatrix * modelviewMatrix * vertex`

find some useful explanations here:
http://robertokoci.com/world-view-projection-matrix-unveiled/
http://db-in.com/blog/2011/04/cameras-on-opengl-es-2-x/

Comment: Can you please tell me way to find projectionMatrix and modelviewMatrix. I tried [link](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/spritetext/MatrixGrabber.html) but it didn't worked for me. Thanks a lot for fast response.